# uvicorn WSGIMiddleware ignoring max_requests?

Tags: python, gunicorn, wsgi, uvicorn

I'm using `gunicorn` with `uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker` and have set `max_requests` to recycle worker processes and avoid memory leaks.

My Application is FastAPI, but also mounts a legacy Django Application with

```
app.mount(..., WSGIMiddleware(django_app))
```

It's basically working fine, but I noticed that `max_requests` only affects the FastAPI Endpoints.

- when only sending requests to FastAPI Endpoints, worker processes are recycled as expected
- when only sending requests to Django Endoints, worker processes are **never** recycled

Why is this, and is there a way to work around it ?